# PHP DomNode nodeValue &gt; &lt issue

Tags: php

I am trying to set the nodeValue of an element like this:

```
$element->nodeValue = get_include_contents(DIR_APP . Config::getParam("layout_dir").$itemTemplateFilePath);
```

`get_include_contents` function returns an html which look like this:

```
<li>Person <b>{{ $name }}</b> is  <span>{{ $age }}</span> years old. <a href="" data-id="{{ $id }}" data-event="Event: 'onclick', Action: 'deleteThePerson'">X</a></li>
```

The problem is that the < and > gets replaced by the `&lt;` and `&gt;`. How to fix that? How to set inner html of an element that contains other html?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add `html` block into your `DOM` tree you should use the `appendChild` and not the `nodeValue` method.

The problem is that you need first to create a `DON Node`.

Here is a trick on how to do this:

```
// This will be the original doc we work on.
$doc1 = new DOMDocument();
$doc1->loadHTML("<html><body><p></p></body></html>");


$element = $doc1->getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

// Here is the trick - we create a new document
$doc2 = new DOMDocument();
$s = '<li>Person <b>{{ $name }}</b> is  <span>{{ $age }}</span> years old. <a href="" data-id="{{ $id }}" data-event="Event: \'onclick\', Action: \'deleteThePerson\'">X</a></li>';
// and load the html we need into that document
$doc2->loadHTML($s);

// Now we can append the node from `doc2` into `doc1`
$element->appendChild($doc1->importNode($doc2->getElementsByTagName('li')[0], true));

echo $doc1->saveHTML();
```

> The important thing that you need to remember is that you must use the `importNode` method in order to move that `node` from `doc2` into `doc1`. Only after you imported that node - you can use the `appendChild` function.

The output in the above example will be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p><li>Person <b>{{ $name }}</b> is  <span>{{ $age }}</span> years old. <a href="" data-id="{{ $id }}" data-event="Event: 'onclick', Action: 'deleteThePerson'">X</a></li></p></body></html>
```

Comment: it says:

`ARGUMENT 1 PASSED TO DOMNODE::APPENDCHILD() MUST BE AN INSTANCE OF DOMNODE, BOOLEAN GIVEN`

Comment: when I do this
`public static function setInnerHTML(\DOMDocument $dom, \DOMNode &$element, $html_string) {
        $dom2 = new \DOMDocument();
        $dom2->loadHTML($html_string);

        $element->appendChild($dom->importNode($dom2->firstChild));
    }`

Comment: I'm almost sure you should use `&$dom` and also node the second parameter of the `importNode` method.

Comment: `ARGUMENT 1 PASSED TO DOMNODE::APPENDCHILD() MUST BE AN INSTANCE OF DOMNODE, BOOLEAN `

Comment: I think the `$dom2->loadHTML()` fails but doesn't give an error cause `$dom2->firstChild` is null or false

Comment: If you are unable to create a new `DOMDocument` element you will not be able to import it's nodes :)

Comment: I FIXED IT!!! i should have used the following code to loadHTML():

`libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom2->loadHTML($html_string, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
        libxml_clear_errors();`

Comment: nice :) I guess you had some problems with the `html` string.